# dynamically children is place in respective groups in android expandable listview

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, expandablelistview

I am working on a client-server project in android.I need to parse xml from url and place it in Expandablelistview.
The problem arises when i am trying to place childs inside each group based on the data coming from server. My code only places the first child values inside first group,and second child value is placed second group.

I need to place "payment_method" and "total" inside first group,and firstname and lastname is place in second group(e.g:Groupname:OrderInfo,customerInfo,
          Childname(OrderInfo):payment_method,total,
          Childname(CustomerInfo):firstname,lastname).My code can placed Childname(OrderInfo) inside OrderInfo group, but i wish to need when i click customerInfo group, the firstname,lastname also displayed customerInfo group.pleasehelp me how is to do.
this is my code:

```
public class SingleMenuItemActivity extends ExpandableListActivity {




static final String KEY_ARTIST = "payment_method";
static final String KEY_FNAME = "firstname";
    static final String KEY_LNAME = "lastname";
static final String KEY_DURATION = "total";
static final String OrderInfo = "OrderInfo";
static final String CustomerInfo = "CustomerInfo";
    private static final String GroupID = "GroupID";
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try{
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.particular);

    SimpleExpandableListAdapter expListAdapter =
        new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
                this,

                createGroupList(),              // Creating group List.
                R.layout.group_row, 

              // Group item layout XML.
                new String[] { "GroupID"},  // the key of group item.e
                new int[] { R.id.order},

                // ID of each group item.-Data under the key goes into this TextView.
                createChildList(),              // childData describes second-level entries.
                R.layout.single_list_item,  
              //  new String[] {"KEY_ARTIST"},  
               // new int[] { R.id.payment_label}  // Keys in childData maps to display.
                  // Layout for sub-level entries(second level).
               new String[] {"KEY_ARTIST","KEY_DURATION","KEY_FNAME","KEY_LNAME"},  
               new int[] { R.id.name_label,R.id.cost_label,R.id.firstname,R.id.lastname}// Keys in childData maps to display.
             //   new int[] { R.id.payment_label,R.id.total_label}     // Data under the keys above go into these TextViews.
            );
        setListAdapter( expListAdapter );       // setting the adapter in the list.

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Errrr +++ " + e.getMessage());
    }
}


 private List createGroupList() {

    Log.d(TAG, "Adding groups values");
    List<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> statusMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    statusMap.put(GroupID, "OrderInfo");
    list.add(statusMap);
    HashMap<String, String> usersMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    usersMap.put(GroupID, "CustomerInfo");
    list.add(usersMap);
    Log.d(TAG, "Adding groups values successfull");
    return list;
   }



/* creatin the HashMap for the children */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private List createChildList() {

    ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
    for( int i = 0 ; i < 1 ; ++i ) { // this -15 is the number of groups(Here it's fifteen)
      /* each group need each HashMap-Here for each group we have 3 subgroups */
      ArrayList secList = new ArrayList();
      for( int n = 0 ; n < 1 ; n++ ) {
        HashMap child = new HashMap();




       String s= getIntent().getStringExtra("payment_method");
       String s1= getIntent().getStringExtra("total");


     child.put( "KEY_ARTIST", s);
     child.put( "KEY_DURATION", s1);

        secList.add( child);
      }
     result.add( secList );
    }
    return result;
}
public void  onContentChanged  () {
    System.out.println("onContentChanged");
    super.onContentChanged();
}
/* This function is called on each child click */
public boolean onChildClick( ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition,int childPosition,long id) {
    System.out.println("Inside onChildClick at groupPosition = " + groupPosition +" Child clicked at position " + childPosition);
    return true;
}

/* This function is called on expansion of the group */
public void  onGroupExpand  (int groupPosition) {
    try{
         System.out.println("Group exapanding Listener => groupPosition = " + groupPosition);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(" groupPosition Errrr +++ " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
 }
```

my doubt is how is place the first child values inside first group,and second child value is placed second group.first child value is placed in first group is successfully completed...but i can't do place the second child value is placed second group.if i have to click the secong group means it is force closed.please help me.how is to do.